# Extracting multiple delimited data elements from three data frame columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame which i have filtered down to those needed. I'm left with three columns with which need further filtering and would like some guidance.

| ID | Column_A | Column_B | Column_C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Data_1;Data_2;Data_3 | Data_4;Data_5 | Data_6 |
| 02 | Data_7 | Data_8;Data_9 | NaN |
| 03 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 04 | Garbage | Data_10;Data_11 | Data_12 |

Finished list

Data_1, Data_2, Data_3.......Data_12

Please note the actual format of the data string is a little different to the above. I have simplified it for this question and ease of programming the concept.

I need to be work through each of the three columns and extract all data elements with a common data structure i.e. begin 'Data_' and followed by a number numerical characters - <[0-9]{3}>.

Some entries have no data, some only one element, others have up to three delimited elements and others have rubbish or poorly formatted data.

I need to ignore all other data - blanks, NaN, poorly formatted.

I'm considering iterating through each column and row, one at a time, splitting the data by ';' and testing each separated element for the correct format and if true adding to list. repeat for columns B and C.

After which I can drop duplicated, sort and index. So that I end up with a unique ordered list.

Can I have your thoughts and guidance.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide the expected output as well.

Answer (score 3):

[`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) then convert [`to_list`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_list.html):

```
out = df.stack().str.extractall(r'(Data_\d+)')[0].to_list()
```

*NB. if your regex is `Data_[0-9]{3}`, use this instead, optionally adding word boundaries (`r'\b(Data_[0-9]{3})\b'`) to ensure having full words only.*

Alternative, if you really need to [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) on `;`, then filter with [`str.fullmatch`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.fullmatch.html):

```
s = df.stack().str.split(';').explode().dropna()

out = s[s.str.fullmatch(r'Data_\d+')].tolist()
```

Output:

```
['Data_1', 'Data_2', 'Data_3', 'Data_4', 'Data_5', 'Data_6', 'Data_7', 'Data_8', 'Data_9', 'Data_10', 'Data_11', 'Data_12']
```

Comment: Thanks, I will look at both options 